# $_SESSION["username"] isn't printing anything

Tags: php, session

In PHP, when navigating from one page to another, the session is not logging.
suddenly the $_SESSION["username"]; that is sent from the login screen, 
in :

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
    echo $username;
    echo $_SESSION["username"]; // THESE 2 ECHOes WORK
```

When in the index:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION["username"];
    // THIS ECHO IS BLANK ALREADY TRIED IT WIWH OTHER ECHOES THE PAGE WORKS
     ?>
```

Comment: if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}   try this

Comment: try if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ //you have session var set else redirect back }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your calling `session_start();` too many times.
Try a simple check if session is started
ex:

```
// start session if not session_id not present
    if(session_id()=='') session_start();
```

You can also check if there is a session variable with:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] !== "") // this checks if its set and does not equal nothing
{
  //do your code
}
else
{
  //reset $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Comment: It worked, but i dont know what was the difference between the normal session_start(), and the if(session_id()=='') session_start();

Comment: your checking to see if session is started thats why. You started a new session every time it erases your session id values